# Is there a way to find daily maximum from hourly data with missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have measured hourly data of ground O3 but with some missing data (marked as NA). I want to calculate daily maximums, but only in case there are more than 17 hourly measurements per date. In case it is less than 18 measurement per date I want to write NA.

```
head(o3sat)
    date        hour    O3
      1/1/2010      0       50.2     
      1/1/2010      1       39.8     
      1/1/2010      2       41.8     
      1/1/2010      3       NA     
      1/1/2010      4       9.2    
      1/1/2010      5       6.0
```

Is there a possibility to add some argument to this function to indicate that at least 75% of the data must be available in a day for the value to be calculated, else the data is removed

```
maximums <- aggregate(o3sat["dnevnik"], list(Date = as.Date(o3sat$datum)),  max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to provide a reproducible example when asking a question. Here, I created an example data frame based on the information you provided. This data frame contains hourly `O3` measurements from `2010-01-01` to `2010-01-03`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

o3sat <- read.table(text = "    date        hour    O3
      '1/1/2010'      0       50.2     
      '1/1/2010'      1       39.8     
      '1/1/2010'      2       41.8     
      '1/1/2010'      3       NA     
      '1/1/2010'      4       9.2    
      '1/1/2010'      5       6.0  ",
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

set.seed(1234)

o3sat_ex <- o3sat %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2010-01-03"), 1), hour = 0:23) %>%
  mutate(O3 = c(o3sat$O3, rnorm(66, 30, 10))) %>%
  mutate(O3 = ifelse(row_number() %in% sample(7:72, 18), NA, O3))
```

We can count how many non-NA value per day using the following code.

```
o3sat_ex %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(sum(!is.na(O3)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date       `sum(!is.na(O3))`
#   <date>                 <int>
# 1 2010-01-01                18
# 2 2010-01-02                17
# 3 2010-01-03                18
```

Based on your description, we would like to calculate the maximum for `2010-01-01` and `2010-01-03`, but not `2010-01-02` as it only contains 17 non-NA values.

Here is one way to achieve the task, we can define a function, `max_helper`, that only returns maximum if the count of non-NA values is larger than 17.

```
max_helper <- function(x, threshold){
  if (sum(!is.na(x)) >= threshold) {
    r <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else { 
    r <- NA
  }
  return(r)
}
```

We can apply this number using the `dplyr` code to get the answer.

```
o3sat_ex2 <- o3sat_ex %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(O3 = max_helper(O3, 18))

o3sat_ex2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   date          O3
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2010-01-01  50.2
# 2 2010-01-02  NA  
# 3 2010-01-03  47.8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a solution in this way:   maximus<-timeAverage(o3sat, avg.time = "day",data.thresh  = 75,statistic="max")

Comment: @СлавицаМалиновић-Милићевић Thanks for sharing. It is from the `openair` package.